# how to integrate ASP.NET Core 2.1 with Vue CLI 3?

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core-2.1, vue-cli-3

I have been trying to create a new project using the new Vue CLI 3 with ASP.Net Core web. I can use dotnet new to create a nice new blank web project, and can use vue create to create a new Vue.js Hello World template but I can't for the life of me get them working together.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be pretty straight forward

- Create a new dotnet project
- Create a folder inside dotnet solution. For instance, VueApp, ClientApp, or something.
- Scaffold a new Vue project inside that folder using Vue cli.
- Change the output directory to point to something like "../../wwwroot/dist"
- Build your app. Take note though if you're building for dev or production, output structure will be different.
- In your `_Layout.cshtml` or `Index.cshtml`, however you want to organize it, reference those outputted files.
- Add `<div id="app"></div>` into your `.cshtml`.
- You're done, enjoy.

Comment: hi..
`Change the output directory to point to something like "../../wwwroot/dist"` Where I need to change. Which file? Vue.config.js ?

Comment: It depends how are you building your files. yes vue.config.js if you are building through console. If you are using Vue Ui then there's a settings button at build action, change folder option to point to wwwroot.

Comment: Hi, is this solution possible with nuxt? or how can I set that?

Comment: Hi, it shouldn't be any different. If using Nuxt, repeat all the steps and also make it drop built files into wwwroot folder. Probably also config file. This may do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54418282/5265610

Answer (score 16):

I wrote a detailed tutorial available at [Medium](https://medium.com/software-ateliers/asp-net-core-vue-template-with-custom-configuration-using-cli-3-0-8288e18ae80b).

You can use Microsoft `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices` NuGet package to specify SpaStaticFiles folder instead of copying client app on build to wwwroot and ignore *.cshtml files and use directly vue `index.html` file.

You can also install `VueCliMiddleware` NuGet to run npm process with client app using Vue CLI 3.0 when your .NET app starts.