# Set path to output folder in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]

Working in windows, I'm able to generate a static site from my nuxt project using

```
$ npx nuxt generate
```

I'm interested in setting the output folder for the generated static files.

I'm reading through https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate which explains that I should be looking at the generate property. However, I don't understand how to modift or access the generate property. How cam I access the generate property?

EDIT; I changed the nuxt.config.js build object to :

```
build: {
publicPath: 'public/',


/*
** You can extend webpack config here
*/
extend(config, ctx) {

}
}
 }
```

Then ran

```
$ npx nuxt generate
```

No public folder is generated

Comment: https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/how-to-set-custom-configuration-for-nuxt-js-generate-task-5055e53c2da5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use below config into nuxt.config.js under module.exports, So your generate folder will be **my-dist** instead of **dist**

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'spa',
  generate: {
    dir: 'my-dist'
  },
...............
.............
}
```

and if you want to use custom folder to keep all js,css and assests under **dist** folder for spa generate then use below config into nuxt.config.js under build object

> publicPath: 'public/'

example:

```
  build: {
    publicPath: 'public/',
.........
............
}
```

Comment: kesinlikle doğru ->
   modules: [
    module.exports = {
      mode: 'spa',
      generate: {
        dir: 'dist'
      }
    }
  ],